# view materializes values ​are duplicated and nulls are added

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

good evening,

I have a materialized view that is created correctly, but I duplicate the records every time I update the table: "tabla_hija".

tests:

-if I update the table "detalle orden", the update is successful. records are not duplicated.

-If I update the table "tabla_hija" the rowids are duplicated and they appear null. How can I do so that if the "tabla_hija" is updated, it does not generate these errors.

obs: The "tabla_hija" has that structure and I cannot change it, it is not associated by primary key, if not by a field called "vvalor"

current structure and content

[image]

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON detalle_ordenes
WITH ROWID
INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON tabla_hija
WITH ROWID
INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

create materialized view vm_prueba2
refresh fast on demand 
with rowid
as

select 
   o.rowid o_rowid,
   c.rowid c_rowid,
   e.rowid e_rowid,
   ordenid,
   o.detalleid,
   o.productoid,
      nvl(c.vdescricion,'') as ddesc,
   e.vdescricion
from detalle_ordenes o, tabla_hija c, tabla_hija e
where
   ( o.estado=c.vvalor(+) and c.tipo_filtro=1 or c.vvalor is null ) and
   ( o.segmento=e.vvalor(+) and e.tipo_filtro=2 or e.vvalor is null );

exec DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('vm_prueba2');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it duplicates because if the vvalor column is null in both conditions it will retrieve two rows from both **c** alias and **e** alias, I would recommend removing the **(vvalor is null)** condition since you already connect it with **estado** and **segmento** from **detalle_ordenes** table with left outer join (+), or reorder the brackets to include only the two "or" sides condition, example:

```
  ( o.estado=c.vvalor(+) and (c.tipo_filtro=1 or c.vvalor is null)) and
   ( o.segmento=e.vvalor(+) and (e.tipo_filtro=2 or e.vvalor is null));
```

best of luck to you.